# Checking if a two values in a df in two different columns exist in a different df?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dfa and dfb that both look like such as below,

```
id      start_time  
ab23     2019-04-01 23:00:00.000
bv63     2019-04-01 23:15:00.000
ab20     2019-04-01 21:00:00.000
bv43     2019-04-01 22:15:00.000

id      start_time  
ab23     2019-04-01 23:00:00.000
bv43     2019-04-01 23:15:00.000
```

I want to find out if an id with the same start_time exists in both dfs?

I tried something like

```
matches = dfa['start_time'].isin(dfb['start_time'])
dfa['id'][matches]
```

but it shows that everyrow in both dfs exist in the bother but that is not the case is something wrong in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join by both columns:

```
out = dfa.merge(dfb, on=['start_time', 'id'])['id']
print (out)
0    ab23
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is there anything I am missing on the date value? Bc I tried both methods and it shows that every id in every row exists with the same start time but that is not the case when I look at the data manually @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - Is possible create sample data also for second `df` ? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with expected output.

Comment: I dont know how to create the sample data here - can I send you the csv since it is very small data size? 1k rows @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - One idea, how working `df = df1.merge(df2, on=['time', 'id'])` ?

Comment: Yes! This seems to give me a a lower more accurate number - why did this work and now the others above? thanks ! @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - Because it test by combinations of `id` and `start_time`, your solution test only by `start_time`

Comment: Thanks :) @Jezrael wish you can by my py tutor